# Facebook page tab application not visible to all users

Tags: facebook, tabs

I created a facebook page tab application, i installed it on [my page](https://www.facebook.com/BeautyDistrict) (it can be found under the fb cover, it's the red/pink box with some white text on it), everything ok so far.

The content is loaded from my server. Both [http](http://quart.ro/beautydistrict)/[https](https://quart.ro/beautydistrict) urls are ok, they are working.

The problem is that some users can't see the application installed on that page. Simply that red box isn't displaying. I have no age restriction and the sandbox mode is disabled.

So far i couldn't find a pattern. The app itself is an contact form. 140 users managed to use it but i have received some extra 20 private messages from user that were unable to find the app.

Thanks

Comment: Ever managed to find out what was the problem? I'm having the same issue and for the life of me, I can't figure out why the tab isn't displayed. In your case, did you check the country restrictions? I'm asking because you mentioned the age restriction but not the country.

Comment: Well, i never managed to figure out why that was happening. But from the messages i received back then (complaints lets say) i figured out some of my users where a bit..dumb (the tab was displayed but they where looking for something else). But i still believe there was an actual issue with the displaying.
Wish i could help you, i kinda gave up back then..